# using Azure IoT Hub as a MQTT broker

Tags: mqtt, messagebroker, azure-iot-hub

Our Current Deployment:

1) several back-end devices running an MQTT client connect to an opensource MQTT broker (Mosquitto)

2) Mosquitto is running on a Linux VM and acts as a broker and a communication point between back-end & front-end devices.

3) Several front-end devices (Mobile App / browser based GUI) connect to the broker. some of the front-end devices read & write to the broker (Sub & Pub) while some front-end only read (Sub)

4) Some front-end devices connect for a few minutes & some front ends are always connected.

5) Although the amount of data being transferred is a few kb, it is sometimes fast changing.

6) No TLS is used for the MQTT traffic & it cannot be enabled on the back-end devices.

This setup works for us, but I am looking for a way to scale up and was considering the azure IoT hub, but I am confused if the IoT hub can be used as a broker or I would need additional components to be deployed for acting as a MQTT broker ?

Answer (score 2):

Azure IoT Hub is not a generic MQTT Broker. There is a built-in the device communications for MQTT protocol. More details can be found in the [Using the MQTT protocol directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly)

For exploring the MQTT Devices (virtual devices) with the Azure IoT Hub (without the coding) can be used a small tool [Azure IoT Hub Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester)

Comment: so does azure have an equivalent of a generic MQTT broker ?

Comment: @Sachin Maybe you can install a third-party MQTT broker (like mosquitto) in a VM on Azure.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT this is what i am doing at the moment and i want to stop the overhead of managing VMs hence looking if azure has an alternative.

Comment: Currently, there is no support for directly device-to-device communications with Azure iot hub. You need do some work by yourself, like routes. For more information you can reference [Azure iot hub routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-process-d2c) and [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-use-azure-functions-with-iot-hub-message-routing/).